# Удаление символов в строке по маске Xx и xX (adventofcode 5 day challenge)

Tags: javascript, массивы, node.js, строки

Необходимо строку в файле (в аттаче) длинной 50000 символов отсортировать по маске Xx и xX и удалить их из строки.

Т.е. строка  `QWERTYUuytrewqio` - возвратит `io` (удаляя по порядку `Uu, Yy, Tt, Rr, Ee, Ww, Qq,`) соотвественно `уисИвВиВСИвВвиУИ` возвратит `уисВСИвиУИ`удаляя `вВ, Ии, вВ или Вв`
Мой алгоритм простенький, но как говориться на что пока могем :) Написано для Node.js - переправить в JS обычный можно без труда.

Мой ответ 9526 элементов массива осталось, из 50к после сортировки. Может кто-то подскажет лучше решение или ошибки есть? Благодарю за ответ заранее.

```
var fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync('1.txt') + '';
var arr = [];
var arr = str.split('');
var con = true;

while(con) {
   con = false; 
   poly(arr); 
}
function poly(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
        for(var j = i+1; j <= arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] === arr[i].toLowerCase() && arr[i] !== arr[j] ||
                arr[j] === arr[i].toUpperCase() && arr[i] !== arr[j] )
            {
                arr.splice(i, 2).toString();
                return con = true;
            }  else i++; 
        }
    }
    return con = false;
}
console.log("Final array is : " + arr.toString());
console.log("Array length is : " + arr.length);
```

[Файл со строкой](https://github.com/icesaw/trash/blob/master/1.txt)

Answer (score 0):

Это был 5 день челленджа кодинга перед рождеством - взятый с adventofcode. Сегодня сам дошел как и что)

```
 var fs = require('fs');
    var str = fs.readFileSync('1.txt') + "";
    var con = true;
    while(con) {
    con = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (str.charCodeAt(i) === (str.charCodeAt(i+1) + 32) ||
                str.charCodeAt(i) === (str.charCodeAt(i+1) - 32)) {
                str = str.replace((str[i] + str[i+1]), "" )
                con = true;
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("String is : " + str);
    console.log("String length is : " + str.length);
```